# Validation (CSS4.0): "overflow-anchor" is not known css property name

Tags: css

I have used some elements which are no longer supported on the latest version, the list is given below

```
overflow-anchor:none
appearance:none
::-ms-input-placeholder
::-ms-input-placeholder
-ms-flex-positive:
-webkit-fill-available
color-adjust:exact
-html-user-drag
-ms-flex-preferred-size
:autofill,
-webkit-autofill,
```

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as CSSS4.0

Comment: CSS 4 is latest version

Comment: It is not. It's [version 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) or [the snapshot](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/) if you prefer it. There is no 4.0

Comment: I see. You are using W3Schools CSS4.0 thing. Note: W3Schools is in no way, shape or form associated with the W3C standards body. I added the tag for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I should use standard styles and avoiding non-standard styles

Answer (score 1):

`::-ms-input-placeholder` is, or was, only supported in Internet Explorer versions 10 and 11. The warning shown is only that and the selector will be ignored by browsers that do not recognise it (non IE 10 & 11 based browsers).

See the Note 2 on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-placeholder-shown).

This has been replaced in modern browsers by [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown).

**Note:** You should try not to use any non-standard styles starting with a hyphen `-` these are usually experimental features and prone to breaking in future versions of the supporting browsers.

Comment: I'm using the ASP .NET MVC framework.
I get the error:

When I build and run this code.

Comment: It will most likely be a warning and not an error.